# DirectSoundCreate how to release the handle?

Tags: c++, windows

when i call the function of "DirectSoundCreate" to get "IDirectSound" pointer, but i couldn't release it when exit the process at the destructor.
Like this:

```
IDirectSound*       m_pDirectSound;
IDirectSoundBuffer* m_pDsSoundBuffer;
HRESULT hResult = DirectSoundCreate(NULL, &m_pDirectSound,NULL ); 
hResult = 
   m_pDirectSound->SetCooperativeLevel
                      (hWnd,DSSCL_NORMAL|DSSCL_EXCLUSIVE|DSSCL_PRIORITY);
```

here release:

```
if(m_pDirectSound)
{
   m_pDirectSound->Release();
}
```

the program will block at here forever!

so anyone can help me? shall i release the pointer `m_pDirectSound`? thanks a lot!

Comment: You're never checking `hResult` after calling the API methods?!? Are you serious, is this going to be productive code?

Comment: Also neither `m_pDirectSound` nor `m_pDsSoundBuffer` is initialized in the code you're showing.

Comment: sorry,it's just example code.in fact i check the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not calling `CoUninitialize()` too soon.  If there are still COM objects active when COM is unloaded, calling `Release()` afterwards can exhibit all kinds of undefined behavior, including crashes and deadlocks.

Comment: I didn't calling CoUninitialize(),and i did't call CoInitiallize() etither,should i call these function?

Comment: Yes. DirectX is a COM-based API. You must call `CoInitialize/Ex()` and `CoUninitialize()` to initialize/finalize COM in every thread that accesses COM objects.

Comment: I don't agree with you,please refer to :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416773(v=vs.85).aspx    The voice can play , i just can't exit the process, it block at release()

Answer (score 2):

sometimes memory leaks may cause such situation.
you should check your program whether there is any memory problem.

Your code is not safe.

```
IDirectSound*       m_pDirectSound = NULL;
IDirectSoundBuffer* m_pDsSoundBuffer = NULL;
HRESULT hResult = DirectSoundCreate(NULL, &m_pDirectSound,NULL ); 
hResult = 
   m_pDirectSound->SetCooperativeLevel
                      (hWnd,DSSCL_NORMAL|DSSCL_EXCLUSIVE|DSSCL_PRIORITY);
if(FAILED(hResult)) return ;
//if not at the constructor you should type 'return hResult'
```

you can visit&download example from this website .
http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut14.html

I learn dx11 from it.

:)

Comment: I have check the function return value, and in fact i can play the sound also,but when i finished, i can't exit the process. it block at the function "release".and i have a full test that here is no memory leaks.